# Average value of $f(x,y,z)$ over region $W$

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone show me how to do this problem?

> Compute the average value of $f(x,y,z)$ over the region $W$.
>
> $f(x,y,z) = xyz$
>
> $W$ : $0 \le z \le y \le x \le 1$

Thank you.

Comment: what are the bounds for $x$ and $z$?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y}xyz\space dz\space dy\space dx =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{2}xy^3\space dy\space dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{8}x^5\space dx=\frac{1}{48}$

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y}\space dz\space dy\space dx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}y\space dy\space dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}x^2\space dx=\frac{1}{6}$

Hence the average value will be $\frac{\frac{1}{48}}{\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{1}{8}$